# Multiple JOIN does not return expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

My application implements comments with tags. When retrieving comments, they can be ordered by manually set order which is defined by additional table. For example, if there are two comments and the are both tagged with two tags: "featured" and "useful", their order of retrieval is set by third table: Order.

If two comments are assigned the same two tags ("featured" and "useful") they can be retrieved by tag name and their order will be different between two queries.

The structure of the database is:

```
Comment:
- id
- text

Tag:
- id
- name

CommentTag:
- id
- tag_id (refernces Tag.id)
- comment_id (references Comment.id)

Order:
- id
- comment_id (references Comment.id)
- tag_id (references Tag.id)
- order
```

The following query is used to retrieve comments:

```
SELECT comment.* FROM comment

    INNER JOIN tag ON (comment.id = tag.comment_id)
    INNER JOIN commenttag ON (tag.tag_id = commenttag.id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN order ON (comment.id = order.comment_id)
    WHERE (
        tag.name = "featured" AND
        (tag.id = order.tag_id OR order.comment_id IS NULL))

    ORDER BY order.order ASC
```

The query works somewhat in some cases. But... comments that are assigned to both tags ("featured" and "useful") but have orders set only for a single tag ("useful") are not returned for the query for the second tag ("featured").
I can get this to work only if ordering object exist for both tags.

Comment table:

```
+----+----------------+
| id | text           |
+----+----------------+
| 1  | first comment  |
+----+----------------+
| 2  | second comment |
+----+----------------+
```

Tag table:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
| 11 | featured      |
+----+---------------+
| 12 | useful        |
+----+---------------+
```

CommentTag table:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | tag_id | comment_id |
+----+---------------------+
| 21 | 11     | 1          |
+----+---------------------+
| 22 | 11     | 2          |
+----+---------------------+
| 23 | 12     | 1          |
+----+---------------------+
| 24 | 12     | 2          |
+----+---------------------+
```

Order table:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
| id | tag_id | comment_id | order |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 23 | 12     | 1          | 6     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 24 | 12     | 2          | 3     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

How can I retrieve comments without ordering here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want the conditions in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM comment c JOIN
     tag t
     ON c.id = t.comment_id JOIN
     commenttag ct
     ON t.tag_id = ct.id AND t.name = 'featured' LEFT JOIN
     order o
     ON c.id = o.comment_id AND
        t.id = o.tag_id 
ORDER BY o.order ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a lifesaver! Any chance I can get an explanation why this did is the case and mine did not work?

Comment: @UrK . . . Because you are using an outer join and the conditions should be in the `ON` clause.